Alexa.SmartVision.SnapshotProvider integration issues
I am working on integrating Alexa.SmartVision.SnapshotProvider into our service so that users can see the snapshots from the camera. I can't get the Amazon Eco show to show the picture from the camera snapshot.
This is what I have done so far.
Discover Response:
{"event":{"header":{"namespace":"Alexa.Discovery","name":"Discover.Response","payloadVersion":"3","messageId":"9cdbafc0-0c02-41b7-9c5f-e525a0d1709d"},"payload":{"endpoints":[{"endpointId":"673bce6823cdxxxxxxx","friendlyName":"front door","description":"front door","manufacturerName":"Sinric Pro","displayCategories":["CAMERA"],"cookie":{"deviceId":"673bce6xxxx"},"capabilities":[{"type":"AlexaInterface","interface":"Alexa.SmartVision.SnapshotProvider","version":"1.1","configuration":{"isAvailable":true,"minRefreshIntervalInSeconds":180}},{"type":"AlexaInterface","interface":"Alexa.EndpointHealth","version":"3.1","properties":{"supported":[{"name":"connectivity"}],"proactivelyReported":true,"retrievable":true}},{"type":"AlexaInterface","interface":"Alexa","version":"3"}],"additionalAttributes":{"customIdentifier":"xxxx"}}]}}}

Response to GetSnapshot with preferOnDemandSnapshot = false
{"event":{"header":{"namespace":"Alexa.SmartVision.SnapshotProvider","name":"Snapshot","messageId":"9ce4d54d-d43d-4b65-9eb7-da16ab78a051","correlationToken":"SUdTVEs6A....nS2V5IjoiREFBUEkifQ==","payloadVersion":"1.1"},"endpoint":{"endpointId":"673bce682xxxxx"},"payload":{"value":{"uri":"https://...../image/preview?token=c030b87dd29a-xxxxxxxxxxx","uriExpirationTime":"2024-12-02T04:37:55.646Z","authenticationType":"ACCESS_TOKEN"},"timeOfSample":"2024-12-02T04:27:55.646Z","uncertaintyInMilliseconds":10000}}}


When I go to Eco Show -> Camera, I can see the camera icon flickers for a second or two but does not show the picture.

Sometimes Alexa never sends GetSnapshot directive when I goto "Cameras" in Eco Show.

When I say Alexa, show me the "front door". Alexa says "front door" does not exisits


Response image size: 1024x768
Writes with following headers
'Content-Type' : 'image/jpeg'
'Content-Length': xxx,
'Content-Disposition' : `inline; filename=xxxxx`

